# Adding Supplemental Documents

Tags: docusignapi

I've tried adding supplemental documents via docusign API but can't define the position on the document. I read one article on View tabs but couldn't find any detailed information. Can someone help me with View Tab? How to assign tabs to recipients?

This is the code I'm using in recipients tab and the document's display property is modal. However I'm getting the error "The view tab is not allowed on a document with display inline. Tab 'View' DocumentId '1'." while sending the document for signature-

```json
"tabs": {
          "viewTabs": [
            {
              "recipientId": "1",
              "tabLabel": "exampleViewTab",
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "xPosition": "0",
              "yPosition": "0"
            }
                     ]
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Our documentation notes "Fields cannot be added to supplements; the recipient actions are the only controls added to supplements."

Reference:
https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=gbo1643332197980&topicId=nfs1578456470024.html&_LANG=enus

Some example JSON of using a supplemental document with a template is below:

```
   {
        "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Composite Templates",
        "emailBlurb": "Composite Templates Sample 1",
        "status": "sent",
        "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "serverTemplates": [{
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "fa0b3318-a870-4fd4-ba3d-13bd3b14f0cf"
            }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [{
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [{
                        "email": "example@gmail.com",
                        "name": "bob smith",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "roleName": "RoleFromTemplateHere"
              
                    }]
    
    
                
                }
            }],
            
        },
        {
                "inlineTemplates": [{
                "sequence": "1",
                "documents":[ 
                    {
                    "display": "modal",
                    "documentBase64": "base64Here",
                    "documentId": "2",
                    "includeInDownload": "True",
                    "name": "Supplemental Document",
                    "signerMustAcknowledge": "view",
                    "templateRequired": "False"
                }
                ]
            }]
        }
        
        ]
    }
```

You can also find code examples of using supplemental documents here: https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/
Under the section "Examples" we have two examples that demonstrate supplemental documents labeled "Supplemental documents in four styles" and "Two templates and added document in an envelope"